# How to parse query row into arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP login sytem in which I use the following query to compare the username and password:

```
    $mQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '" . 
    $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['user'])) ."' AND  pass= '" . 
    $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass'])) . "'");
```

There are other fields in the user row besides 'user' and 'pass', like 'name' and 'email'. How can I get all these fields into an array?

Comment: You're using MD5 to hash your passwords? No. Please. You might as well use plain text because without a salt this is *completely* useless. You're also using `mysqli` incorrectly, where any user data should be injected with [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). It's completely surreal that you're hashing the username as well, as I've never seen that done before.

Comment: And why `MD5` your username?

Comment: It's only temporary. I'm fixing them after I find a solution for the row parsing.

Comment: The solution is to read the mysqli documentation. There are many very good examples of usage there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 and later, `fetch_all` will return all rows as an array.  If you specify MYSQLI_ASSOC as the result type, each element in the array will be an associative array of fields, indexed by name.

```
// having done the query above

$rows = $mQuery->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  print "email: " . $row['email'] . "<br />";
  // etc
}
```

for earlier versions, you'd do it manually:

```
$rows = array();

while ($row = $mQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  $rows[] = $row;

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  print "email: " . $row['email'] . "<br />";
  // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna start with the manual...

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($mQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

or

`$row = $mQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

As you are using object notation, go with option 2.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will help:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $mQuery))
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```